# The start of string token ^ is ignored into an awk script?

Tags: shell, script, awk

For learning purpose I made a very simple `awk` script.
It should find the name and the size of some binaries inside `/usr/bin`.

Here's an example of the script :

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

func round(n) {
  return int(n + 0.5)
}


BEGIN { FS=" " }
/^x.+gcc/ && $5 > 30000 { print $9, $5, round($5/1024)"K" }
END { print "Done!" }
```

But when I'm running it there's no results:

```tty
~/tmp$ ls -lL /usr/bin | ./test.awk
Done!
```

I'm sure this is the start of string token `^` because if I replace

```awk
/^x86.+gcc/ && $5 > 30000 { print $9, $5, round($5/1024)"K" }
```

by

```awk
/.+gcc/ && $5 > 30000 { print $9, $5, round($5/1024)"K" }
```

The result is:

```tty
~/tmp$ ls -lL /usr/bin | ./test.awk
gcc 1154192 1127K
gcc-9 1154192 1127K
gcc-ar 35464 35K
gcc-ar-9 35464 35K
gcc-nm 35464 35K
gcc-nm-9 35464 35K
gcc-ranlib 35464 35K
gcc-ranlib-9 35464 35K
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc 1154192 1127K
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9 1154192 1127K
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar 35464 35K
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-9 35464 35K
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm 35464 35K
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-9 35464 35K
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib 35464 35K
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-9 35464 35K
Done!
```

Which obviously shows me more results than what I want.

Why `awk` is behaving like this ?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is `awk` behaving like this?

Because `/^x86.+gcc/` tests the entire line of input, not the 9th field of input nor the future output (which is unknown at the time anyway). No line generated by `ls -lL /usr/bin` starts with `x86`.

<sub>Side note: [do not parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).</sub>